# mouse and keyboard not working on Ubuntu 20.04 remote desktop after login

Tags: 20.04, xrdp

I was trying to control Ubuntu 20.04 remotely via windows 10.

I installed xrdp with the scripts from https://c-nergy.be/.

After logging in on windows, the screen was refreshing but the mouse and keyboard did not respond.

The Ubuntu system is installed on a laptop, and the keyboard and mouse are normal.

Here is the log file.

```
[20210624-20:53:08] [DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET6 ::ffff:192.168.1.112 port 3389)
[20210624-20:53:08] [DEBUG] Closed socket 11 (AF_INET6 :: port 3389)
[20210624-20:53:08] [INFO ] Using default X.509 certificate: /etc/xrdp/cert.pem
[20210624-20:53:08] [INFO ] Using default X.509 key file: /etc/xrdp/key.pem
[20210624-20:53:08] [DEBUG] TLSv1.3 enabled
[20210624-20:53:08] [DEBUG] TLSv1.2 enabled
[20210624-20:53:08] [DEBUG] Security layer: requested 11, selected 1
[20210624-20:53:08] [INFO ] connected client computer name: HUSKY-K610C
[20210624-20:53:08] [INFO ] adding channel item name rdpdr chan_id 1004 flags 0x80800000
[20210624-20:53:08] [INFO ] adding channel item name rdpsnd chan_id 1005 flags 0xc0000000
[20210624-20:53:08] [INFO ] adding channel item name cliprdr chan_id 1006 flags 0xc0a00000
[20210624-20:53:08] [INFO ] adding channel item name drdynvc chan_id 1007 flags 0xc0800000
[20210624-20:53:08] [INFO ] TLS connection established from ::ffff:: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
[20210624-20:53:08] [DEBUG] xrdp_00000dc2_wm_login_mode_event_00000001
[20210624-20:53:08] [INFO ] Cannot find keymap file /etc/xrdp/km-00000804.ini
[20210624-20:53:08] [INFO ] Cannot find keymap file /etc/xrdp/km-00000804.ini
[20210624-20:53:08] [INFO ] Loading keymap file /etc/xrdp/km-00000409.ini
[20210624-20:53:08] [WARN ] local keymap file for 0x00000804 found and doesn't match built in keymap, using local keymap file
[20210624-20:53:08] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: connecting to sesman ip 127.0.0.1 port 3350
[20210624-20:53:08] [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sesman connect ok
[20210624-20:53:08] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sending login info to session manager, please wait...
[20210624-20:53:08] [DEBUG] return value from xrdp_mm_connect 0
[20210624-20:53:10] [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: login failed for display 0
[20210624-20:53:10] [DEBUG] xrdp_mm_module_cleanup
[20210624-20:53:10] [DEBUG] Closed socket 18 (AF_INET6 ::1 port 47924)
[20210624-20:53:25] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: connecting to sesman ip 127.0.0.1 port 3350
[20210624-20:53:25] [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sesman connect ok
[20210624-20:53:25] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sending login info to session manager, please wait...
[20210624-20:53:25] [DEBUG] return value from xrdp_mm_connect 0
[20210624-20:53:25] [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: login successful for display 10
[20210624-20:53:25] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: started connecting
[20210624-20:53:25] [INFO ] lib_mod_log_peer: xrdp_pid=3522 connected to X11rdp_pid=3544 X11rdp_uid=1000 X11rdp_gid=1000 client_ip=::ffff
[20210624-20:53:25] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: connected ok
[20210624-20:53:25] [DEBUG] xrdp_mm_connect_chansrv: chansrv connect successful
[20210624-20:53:25] [DEBUG] Closed socket 18 (AF_INET6 ::1 port 47926)
[20210624-20:55:19] [DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET6 ::ffff:192.168.1.112 port 3389)
[20210624-20:55:19] [DEBUG] xrdp_mm_module_cleanup
[20210624-20:55:19] [DEBUG] Closed socket 19 (AF_UNIX)
[20210624-20:55:19] [DEBUG] Closed socket 20 (AF_UNIX)
[20210624-20:55:38] [INFO ] Socket 12: AF_INET6 connection received from ::ffff:59.78.0.91 port 7585
[20210624-20:55:38] [DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET6 ::ffff:192.168.1.112 port 3389)
[20210624-20:55:38] [DEBUG] Closed socket 11 (AF_INET6 :: port 3389)
[20210624-20:55:38] [INFO ] Using default X.509 certificate: /etc/xrdp/cert.pem
[20210624-20:55:38] [INFO ] Using default X.509 key file: /etc/xrdp/key.pem
[20210624-20:55:38] [DEBUG] TLSv1.3 enabled
[20210624-20:55:38] [DEBUG] TLSv1.2 enabled
[20210624-20:55:38] [DEBUG] Security layer: requested 11, selected 1
[20210624-20:55:38] [DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET6 ::ffff:192.168.1.112 port 3389)
[20210624-20:55:38] [INFO ] Socket 12: AF_INET6 connection received from ::ffff:59.78.0.91 port 7586
[20210624-20:55:38] [DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET6 ::ffff:192.168.1.112 port 3389)
[20210624-20:55:38] [DEBUG] Closed socket 11 (AF_INET6 :: port 3389)
[20210624-20:55:38] [INFO ] Using default X.509 certificate: /etc/xrdp/cert.pem
[20210624-20:55:38] [INFO ] Using default X.509 key file: /etc/xrdp/key.pem
[20210624-20:55:38] [DEBUG] TLSv1.3 enabled
[20210624-20:55:38] [DEBUG] TLSv1.2 enabled
[20210624-20:55:38] [DEBUG] Security layer: requested 11, selected 1
[20210624-20:55:38] [INFO ] connected client computer name: HUSKY-K610C
[20210624-20:55:38] [INFO ] adding channel item name rdpdr chan_id 1004 flags 0x80800000
[20210624-20:55:38] [INFO ] adding channel item name rdpsnd chan_id 1005 flags 0xc0000000
[20210624-20:55:38] [INFO ] adding channel item name cliprdr chan_id 1006 flags 0xc0a00000
[20210624-20:55:38] [INFO ] adding channel item name drdynvc chan_id 1007 flags 0xc0800000
[20210624-20:55:38] [INFO ] TLS connection established from ::ffff: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
[20210624-20:55:40] [DEBUG] xrdp_000011c0_wm_login_mode_event_00000001
[20210624-20:55:40] [INFO ] Cannot find keymap file /etc/xrdp/km-00000804.ini
[20210624-20:55:40] [INFO ] Cannot find keymap file /etc/xrdp/km-00000804.ini
[20210624-20:55:40] [INFO ] Loading keymap file /etc/xrdp/km-00000409.ini
[20210624-20:55:40] [WARN ] local keymap file for 0x00000804 found and doesn't match built in keymap, using local keymap file
[20210624-20:55:46] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: connecting to sesman ip 127.0.0.1 port 3350
[20210624-20:55:46] [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sesman connect ok
[20210624-20:55:46] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sending login info to session manager, please wait...
[20210624-20:55:46] [DEBUG] return value from xrdp_mm_connect 0
[20210624-20:55:46] [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: login successful for display 10
[20210624-20:55:46] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: started connecting
[20210624-20:55:46] [INFO ] lib_mod_log_peer: xrdp_pid=4544 connected to X11rdp_pid=3544 X11rdp_uid=1000 X11rdp_gid=1000 client_ip=::ffff:
[20210624-20:55:46] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: connected ok
[20210624-20:55:46] [DEBUG] xrdp_mm_connect_chansrv: chansrv connect successful
[20210624-20:55:46] [DEBUG] Closed socket 18 (AF_INET6 ::1 port 47944)
[20210624-20:55:54] [DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET6 ::ffff:192.168.1.112 port 3389)
[20210624-20:55:54] [DEBUG] xrdp_mm_module_cleanup
[20210624-20:55:54] [DEBUG] Closed socket 19 (AF_UNIX)
[20210624-20:55:54] [DEBUG] Closed socket 20 (AF_UNIX)
[20210624-20:59:23] [INFO ] Socket 12: AF_INET6 connection received from ::ffff:59.78.0.91 port 11866
[20210624-20:59:23] [DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET6 ::ffff:192.168.1.112 port 3389)
[20210624-20:59:23] [DEBUG] Closed socket 11 (AF_INET6 :: port 3389)
[20210624-20:59:23] [INFO ] Using default X.509 certificate: /etc/xrdp/cert.pem
[20210624-20:59:23] [INFO ] Using default X.509 key file: /etc/xrdp/key.pem
[20210624-20:59:23] [DEBUG] TLSv1.3 enabled
[20210624-20:59:23] [DEBUG] TLSv1.2 enabled
[20210624-20:59:23] [DEBUG] Security layer: requested 11, selected 1
[20210624-20:59:23] [DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET6 ::ffff:192.168.1.112 port 3389)
[20210624-20:59:23] [INFO ] Socket 12: AF_INET6 connection received from ::ffff:59.78.0.91 port 11867
[20210624-20:59:23] [DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET6 ::ffff:192.168.1.112 port 3389)
[20210624-20:59:23] [DEBUG] Closed socket 11 (AF_INET6 :: port 3389)
[20210624-20:59:23] [INFO ] Using default X.509 certificate: /etc/xrdp/cert.pem
[20210624-20:59:23] [INFO ] Using default X.509 key file: /etc/xrdp/key.pem
[20210624-20:59:23] [DEBUG] TLSv1.3 enabled
[20210624-20:59:23] [DEBUG] TLSv1.2 enabled
[20210624-20:59:23] [DEBUG] Security layer: requested 11, selected 1
[20210624-20:59:23] [INFO ] connected client computer name: HUSKY-K610C
[20210624-20:59:23] [INFO ] adding channel item name rdpdr chan_id 1004 flags 0x80800000
[20210624-20:59:23] [INFO ] adding channel item name rdpsnd chan_id 1005 flags 0xc0000000
[20210624-20:59:23] [INFO ] adding channel item name cliprdr chan_id 1006 flags 0xc0a00000
[20210624-20:59:23] [INFO ] adding channel item name drdynvc chan_id 1007 flags 0xc0800000
[20210624-20:59:23] [INFO ] TLS connection established from ::ffff: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
[20210624-20:59:23] [DEBUG] xrdp_00001823_wm_login_mode_event_00000001
[20210624-20:59:23] [INFO ] Cannot find keymap file /etc/xrdp/km-00000804.ini
[20210624-20:59:23] [INFO ] Cannot find keymap file /etc/xrdp/km-00000804.ini
[20210624-20:59:23] [INFO ] Loading keymap file /etc/xrdp/km-00000409.ini
[20210624-20:59:23] [WARN ] local keymap file for 0x00000804 found and doesn't match built in keymap, using local keymap file
[20210624-20:59:27] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: connecting to sesman ip 127.0.0.1 port 3350
[20210624-20:59:27] [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sesman connect ok
[20210624-20:59:27] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sending login info to session manager, please wait...
[20210624-20:59:27] [DEBUG] return value from xrdp_mm_connect 0
[20210624-20:59:27] [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: login successful for display 10
[20210624-20:59:27] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: started connecting
[20210624-20:59:27] [INFO ] lib_mod_log_peer: xrdp_pid=6179 connected to X11rdp_pid=3544 X11rdp_uid=1000 X11rdp_gid=1000 client_ip=::ffff:59.78.0.91 client_port=11867
[20210624-20:59:27] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: connected ok
[20210624-20:59:27] [DEBUG] xrdp_mm_connect_chansrv: chansrv connect successful
[20210624-20:59:27] [DEBUG] Closed socket 18 (AF_INET6 ::1 port 47982)
[20210624-20:59:34] [DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET6 ::ffff:192.168.1.112 port 3389)
[20210624-20:59:34] [DEBUG] xrdp_mm_module_cleanup
[20210624-20:59:34] [DEBUG] Closed socket 19 (AF_UNIX)
[20210624-20:59:34] [DEBUG] Closed socket 20 (AF_UNIX)
[20210624-20:59:37] [DEBUG] Closed socket 11 (AF_INET6 :: port 3389)
[20210624-21:01:19] [INFO ] address [0.0.0.0] port [3389] mode 1
[20210624-21:01:19] [INFO ] listening to port 3389 on 0.0.0.0
[20210624-21:01:19] [INFO ] xrdp_listen_pp done
[20210624-21:01:19] [DEBUG] Closed socket 7 (AF_INET6 :: port 3389)
[20210624-21:01:21] [INFO ] starting xrdp with pid 1016
[20210624-21:01:21] [INFO ] address [0.0.0.0] port [3389] mode 1
[20210624-21:01:21] [INFO ] listening to port 3389 on 0.0.0.0
[20210624-21:01:21] [INFO ] xrdp_listen_pp done
```

Answer (score 5):

I tried a solution from elsewhere to run:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

But that did not seem to work. But following this solution here worked for me on Xubuntu 20.04 using xfce: https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xorgxrdp/issues/164#issuecomment-710594486

> The fix for me was to add Option "CoreKeyboard" and Option
> "CorePointer" to the inputdevices in ***/etc/X11/xrdp/xorg.conf*** since the
> inputdevices in the serverlayout section are apparently ignored so no
> core pointer and keyboard exists, which leads to forced default
> devices. No idea why this is suddenly the case, it worked fine on
> ubuntu 18.04, but broke for me in 20.04.

```
Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier "xrdpKeyboard"
    Driver "xrdpkeyb"
    Option "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier "xrdpMouse"
    Driver "xrdpmouse"
    Option "CorePointer"
EndSection
```

Comment: I had to change one of the commands slightly
`sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all --reinstall`

And also run `systemctl restart gmd3 xrpd*` to apply the changes.

Answer (score 0):

In case if anyone comes across this question. In Debian 12 I was using xrdp to connect from Windows. When I changed a "Num Lock on Boot" setting in "Input devices > Keyboard > Hardware" to "do not change" from "enabled", remote keyboard stopped working. When I switched it back to "enabled", keyboard came back.